# exception with WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle()

Tags: c#, wpf

some times, ArgumentOutOfRangeException throwed by EnsureHandle, see
callstack

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.GetDpiForCurrentMonitor()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget..ctor(IntPtr hwnd)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters parameters)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle()
```

code just as following

```
var owner = new Window
{
    Height = 1,
    Width = 1,
    ShowActivated = false,
    ShowInTaskbar = false,
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow
};          
new WindowInteropHelper(owner).EnsureHandle();
```

somebody has any ideas about this?

Comment: Why do you need a window with `Width` and `Height` equals 1?

Comment: just need a hide toolwindow as the owner of some kind of window.